# cakephp, jquery, .ajax()

Tags: php, cakephp, jquery

I've been stuck with the retrieving of my sent variable trough an ajax POST function. Could you help me out?

My Jquery code:

```
$.ajaxSetup ({
        cache: false
    });

var selected = new Array();    
$(document).ready(function() {       
    $('.value').click(function () {                      
        if($(this).hasClass('strong'))
        {
            selected.splice(selected.indexOf(this.innerHTML), 1);  
            submitData(selected);
            $(this).removeClass('strong');
        }
        else 
        {
            selected.push(this.innerHTML);
            submitData(selected);
            $(this).addClass('strong')                         
        }
    });
});

function submitData(arDat)    {
    var arrayData =  {"param1" : JSON.stringify(arDat)};

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://localhost.local/coconut/trunk/challenges/values',           
        data: arrayData,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
            console.log(arrayData);
        },
        error: function(message){
            alert(message);
        }
    });
}
```

My CakePHP Controller function:

```
function values() {
        if ($this->RequestHandler->isAjax()) {
            $this->autoRender = false;
            Configure::write('debug', 0);
            $params = json_decode($_POST['param1']);
            //$result = json_encode($params);
            $this->set('submitValue', $params);
        } else {
            $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'challenges', 'action' => 'index'));
        }
    }
```

And in a view.ctp file:

```
<?php debug($submitValue); ?>
```

But I get the following error: 
Notice (8): Undefined variable: submitValue

In firebug I see this:

```
Parametersapplication/x-www-form-urlencoded
param1  ["Business","Life","Health"]
Source
param1=%5B%22Business%22%2C%22Life%22%2C%22Health%22%5D
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Edit:

A bit more clarification about what I want.. I want to use   $this->set('submitValue', $params); (so $submitValue) elsewhere in another view.

Comment: my initial observation is that "json_decode()" won't decode the URI encoded string as you expect, but I could be wrong there. A JSON encoded string would look like {"param1":["Business","Life","Health"]} in this case. What you're sending to the server is a URI Encoded string.

Comment: What is the language you are sending to the server ?
and receiving

Comment: @ jcolebrand, I changed "json_decode()" to decodeURI no changes :(.

Comment: @UserB JSON strings, I suppose?

Comment: you should decodeuri in the json_decode

Comment: and encode the sent data

Comment: looks like your request isn't properly identifying as an ajax request. From the looks of it, `$this->RequestHandler->isAjax()` is returning false.

Comment: @Kenaniah, how do you know that?

Comment: @Arvind by the fact that his code only sets submitValue if it's true. Granted the assumption is a long shot, but assuming that false redirects to the same template, it's a possibility.

Comment: I got it working, if someone is interested msg me.

Comment: That wasn't really an answer. If it's not too much trouble, could you go ahead and post your solution?

Answer (score 0):

The CakePHP function 'isAjax()' checks to see if a request is a Prototype Ajax request.

You aren't using Prototype, you're using jQuery - so presumably it's always returning false, and so submitValue is never set.